# model.compile() fails with every but 'accuracy' metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a simple MLP, and coded this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import Input

def get_stats_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

And in `main.py`:

```
get_stats_model()
```

Which works perfectly, as long as the metrics is `'accuracy'` only. when trying with both `'accuracy'` and `'AUC'`, just `'AUC'`, or `'mean_absolute_error'`, like:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import Input

def get_stats_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['AUC'])
    
    return model
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    get_stats_model()
  File "/home/giuliano/Desktop/tfg/workspace/root/final/exp/mlp.py", line 64, in get_stats_model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['AUC'])
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 222, in compile
    masks=masks)
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 871, in _handle_metrics
    self._per_output_metrics[i], target, output, output_mask)
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 842, in _handle_per_output_metrics
    metric_fn, y_true, y_pred, weights=weights, mask=mask)
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 1033, in call_metric_function
    update_ops = metric_fn.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weights)
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 42, in decorated
    update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 318, in update_state
    matches = self._fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 1660, in __init__
    if num_thresholds <= 1:
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 757, in __bool__
    self._disallow_bool_casting()
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 526, in _disallow_bool_casting
    self._disallow_in_graph_mode("using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
  File "/home/giuliano/anaconda3/envs/tfg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 515, in _disallow_in_graph_mode
    " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

And I just can't figure out why the only change in metrics is causing such error, and there doesn't seem to be much information on the internet.

My packages versions are:

```
Keras==2.3.1
tensorflow==2.1.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same tensorflow version, but my keras version is 2.2.4; For me your code is working with all kinds of metrics

Comment: It works for me. I have the same keras version 2.3.1. One thing I'll suggest in new virtual environment. Install the packages and try the code. Second you can try importing keras from tensorflow itself. ie. `from tensorflow.keras import dense`

Comment: Thanks to both, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments

> 1. Creating a `Virtual Environment` and
> 2. **`Importing Keras`** using the code, `from tensorflow import keras`
>
> has resolved the issue. (paraphrased from drops and Aniket Bote).